How can I solve error while installing R package "Error in if (nzchar(cxx)) { : argument is of length zero" problem?
> install.packages("~/Desktop/treeclim_2.0.6.0.tar", repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)
* installing *source* package ‘treeclim’ ...
** package ‘treeclim’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
make: *** /Users/user/.R/Makevars: Is a directory.  Stop.
Warning in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  :
  running command 'make -f 'Makevars' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' -f '/Users/user/.R/Makevars' compilers' had status 2
Error in if (nzchar(cxx)) { : argument is of length zero
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/treeclim’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/user/Desktop/treeclim_2.0.6.0.tar’ had non-zero exit status


How can I solve this problem?
RStudio Version 2024.04.0+735
Apple M1
macOS Sonoma 14.5

sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5


Not sure about the rest but the first error message is pretty explicit: “/Users/user/.R/Makevars: Is a directory.” — Makevars should be a file, not a directory. It being a directory makes no sense, so delete it.

Thank you for your comment. How can I do it?

Please do not post the same question multiple times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78485857/how-can-i-solve-error-in-if-nzcharcxx-argument-is-of-length-zero-probl

Voting to close as dupe of your other question

@ormbtnk I don’t understand the question. Are you asking how to delete a directory?

"Makevars should be a file, not a directory. It being a directory makes no sense, so delete it." How can I do it?

unlink('/Users/user/.R/Makevars', recursive = TRUE) inside R. Or rm -r /Users/user/.R/Makevars outside R in a terminal. Or navigate to the folder inside Finder and delete it (but .R is invisible, so you will need to show hidden file by pressing Cmd+Shift+dot).

Now I encountered this problem. What should I do?
***** ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'emutls_w' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [treeclim.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘treeclim’

removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/treeclim’ *****

